# Winform .NET enhanced treeview?

Tags: winforms, treeview

What is a good TreeView replacement with added features over the standard one that comes with vs.net 2008? please include both a free and commercial options.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you're looking for that's not in the std TreeView.

Comment: I need it to handle multiple columns, and would be nice if you could attach it to a table instead of having to populate it esp with parent/child data

Comment: It is called a TreeList, every component vendor has one.

Answer (score 3):

[TreeViewAdv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/) has always been my favorite.

Answer (score 1):

You could to take a look into [RadTreeView for WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/treeview.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is a **free** and **comprehensive** list/tree view control I found on code project by **Phillip Piper** called **ObjectListView**.

It has all the standard features and more. It is well thought out and professionally made. I my opinion it easily stands up to the popular commercial solutions available. I would recommend it to any developer looking for a free feature-rich list/tree view control for their winforms application.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

### Here's a list of features from the documentation. http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

> - It easily transforms a collection of model objects in a fully functional ListView, including automatically sorting and grouping.
> - It can easily edit the values shown in the ListView.
> - It supports tri-state check-boxes (on, off, indeterminate), even in virtual mode, and on subitems.
> - It supports heavily customisable tool tips for both cells and column headers.
> - It can trivially produce nice reports from the ListView.
> - It supports all ListView views (report, tile, large and small icons).
> - It supports owner drawing, including rendering animated GIFs.
> - Its columns can be fixed-width or limited to a minimum/maximum.
> - It shows a highly customisable "list is empty" message when the list is empty (obviously).
> - Its row height can be explicitly set.
> - It supports user selection of visible columns by right clicking on the header.
> - It supports columns that automatically resize to fill any unoccupied width.
> - It supports hot tracking, with text font/color changes and with decorations.
> - It supports image and text overlays, as well as arbitrary overlays (the personal information box) and decorations (the love hearts).
> - It has extensive support for drag and drop.
> - It supports hyperlinks in cells.
> - It supports column headers being styled (normal, hot and pressed states), plus having images and even vertical text.
> - It supports many group formatting options, including collapsible groups. Groups can be shown on virtual lists!
> - It has a version (**TreeListView**) which combines a tree structure with the columns of a ListView.
> - It has a version (**VirtualObjectListView**) that supports millions of rows.
> - It has a version (**FastObjectListView**) that can build a list of 100,000 objects in less than 0.1 seconds.
> - It has a version (**DataListView**) that supports data binding, and another (FastDataListView) that supports data binding on large (100,000+) data sets.
> - It makes implementing your own virtual list simple through the IVirtualListDataSource interface.
> - It supports filtering, including showing and highlighting rows that match a given string (including regex and prefix match).
> - It supports animations on a cell, row or the whole list. [v2.4]
> - It supports Excel-style filtering. [v2.5]

Answer (score 0):

Another name for such a component is TreeListView. If you need a WinForms TreeListView control that can be populate from a data table, look at [iGrid.NET in TreeListView mode](http://10tec.com/articles/treelistview-control.aspx). You can do what you need with just one method call using this control.