# How to Insert Picture in TreeNode

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, treeview

Pretty straight forward question. Is it possible to insert a picture in a treenode like so:

[image: TreeNode Picture]

I add all my treenodes very basically by adding a couple nodes. I was looking to perhaps add it like so:

```
Dim nPicture As New TreeNode
nPicture.Image = My.Resources.SchemaConfig
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nPicture)
```

To me, this would've been how I'd add it but obviously we can't do it so easily.

I've searched for the answer and only found stuff relating to the icons or image keys that we can add on the begining of the treenode. I'd provide code if I had some... I really have no clue on how to proceed with this.

Comment: Depend's what would be the condition? How would you like it to show (what event), the question lacks detail. Could you please update the question?

Comment: It might be easier to show the image in a `ToolStripDropDown` popup, or in a subpanel beside the treeview.

Comment: @436f6465786572 I'd just add it using treeview.Nodes.Add() if that's what you're asking... I'll update it

Comment: The main problem with the `TreeView` is the inability to specify the node height for a specific node, independent of the other nodes. You will probably need to use a third party `TreeView` control, some links here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126201/winform-net-enhanced-treeview

Comment: There are lots and lots of "TreeList" controls around.  You'll have to go shopping by yourself.